# Rails saving 0 instead of string from model collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been trying to create a basic rails application. I used generate to create a basic scaffold and I have setup a belongs_to relationship between players and teams so players belong_to team and team has_many players.

My form view looks like this

```
<%= form_for(@team) do |f| %>
  <% if @team.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@team.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this team from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @team.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Playerone %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :Playerone, Player.all, :firstname, :firstname %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Playertwo %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :Playertwo, Player.all, :firstname, :firstname %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try to create a new team I get the dropdowns as I want them with the players first name to select from but then when it is saved it saves 0 as the record.

Listing teams

Playerone   Playertwo
0   0   Show    Edit    Destroy

New Team

Originally I had the collection select like this 
`<%= f.collection_select :Playertwo, Player.all, :id, :firstname %>`
This inserts the ID but I want the text to be inserted instead.

I have looked over reams and reams of documentation and have come up trumps as I am still learning.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then it depends on your migration.  If you created an integer field in your database, saving the string will save 0.

You can (a), change your migration to use a string instead of an integer.

You can (b), use the id, and display the name by looking up the name.

```
f.collection_select :Playertwo, Player.all, :id, :firstname
```

You can either get the name from the team belongs_to playerone and playertwo,

```
class Team
  belongs_to :playerone, :class_name => "Player"
  belongs_to :playertwo, :class_name => "Player"
end

<%= team.playerone.firstname %>
```

or you can delegate the firstname to the players.

```
class Team
  belongs_to :playerone, :class_name => "Player"
  belongs_to :playertwo, :class_name => "Player"
  delegate :firstname, :to => :playerone, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
  delegate :firstname, :to => :playertwo, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
end

<%= team.playerone_firstname %>
```

Or you can (c) use the belongs_to, which uses an integer.  Please look up the documentation
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: I mentioned that I originally had :id but this put the ID of the player whereas I want the string of the player firstname.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Absolutely awesome ! Thanks a bunch man ! Originally I had an integer for the value then I changed the migration to string and did a rake db:reset. A lot of the documentation confused me a little being new to the rails world. That is a massive help.

Comment: ok I changed my model for team to look like this 
`class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :playerone, :class_name => "Player"
  belongs_to :playertwo, :class_name => "Player"
end` and changed my view to use `  <%= @team.playertwo.firstname %>` but now I get 'NoMethodError in Teams#show

Showing c:/Sites/TWL/app/views/teams/show.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `firstname' for nil:NilClass' any ideas ?

Comment: On a previous answer (different question) someone told me I didn't need the relationships. I have hit the documentation and your answer has sent me in the right direction. Thanks again.